# How can I declare path for bootstrap navbar search form using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search, navbar, sunspot

I want to search textbooks in landing page but it is not working.
I had to go /textbooks page and then I can search.
Also, I want to fulltext search. I am using sunspot & solr. But full text search not working. If I have a textbook title called "Algorithm".
If I search "algo" I want to be searchable. Can you help?

I have codes below.

views/layouts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>
    <% if content_for? :title %>
        <%= yield :title %>
    <% else %>
        Udeal
    <% end %>
  </title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>

<%= render 'partials/navbar' %>

<%= render 'partials/flash_notification' %>

<%= yield %>

</body>

</html>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  get '/about', to: 'home#about'

  resources :textbooks
  get '/textbooks/search', to: 'textbooks#search'
  devise_for :users
```

_navbar.html.erb:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form_tag(textbooks_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", html: {class: 'form-group'}) do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search all deals", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => 'btn btn-default',:title => nil%>
          <% end %>
      </form>
```

my TextbooksController:

```
class TextbooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_textbook, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def search
    @search = Textbook.search do
      keywords(params[:q])
    end
  end

  def index
    @textbooks = Textbook.all
    @search = Textbook.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      #keywords params[:search]
    end
    @textbooks = @search.results
  end
```

Textbook model:

```
class Textbook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    searchable do
        text :title, :default_boost => 2
        text :subject
    end
```

below is my index.html.erb for Textbook page

```
<div>
          <%= form_tag textbooks_path, :method => :get do %>
            <p>
            <a style="color:#000000" title="Suggest!" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Title or Subject">
              <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
            </a>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :title => nil, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

EDIT:

I typed rake routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                              home#index
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               home#about
        search_textbooks GET    /textbooks/search(.:format)    textbooks#search
               textbooks GET    /textbooks(.:format)           textbooks#index
                         POST   /textbooks(.:format)           textbooks#create
            new_textbook GET    /textbooks/new(.:format)       textbooks#new
           edit_textbook GET    /textbooks/:id/edit(.:format)  textbooks#edit
                textbook GET    /textbooks/:id(.:format)       textbooks#show
                         PATCH  /textbooks/:id(.:format)       textbooks#update
                         PUT    /textbooks/:id(.:format)       textbooks#update
                         DELETE /textbooks/:id(.:format)       textbooks#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: what your routes look like ?

Comment: in your console type `rake routes | grep search`. Then copy the path and paste it to your form url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**_navbar.html.erb** would be:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form_tag(search_textbooks_path, :method => "get", html: {class: 'form-group', id: "search-form"}) do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search all deals", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => 'btn btn-default',:title => nil%>
          <% end %>
      </form>
```

Previously your form url was wrong. If you still face the same problem, then post your `log` errors.

Your search method would be:

```
def search
    @search = Textbook.search do
       fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @textbooks = @search.results
  end
```

Comment: I get NameError in Home#index

Comment: I get same NameError in Home#index

I get red highlight on the line:
<%= form_tag(search_textbooks_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", html: {class: 'form-group'}) do %>

Comment: I just edited in routes.rb get '/search/textbooks', to: 'textbooks#search'
Not get 'textbooks/search', to: 'textbooks#search'

rake routes give me:
search_textbooks GET    /search/textbooks(.:format)    textbooks#search

The error is gone. But stil I have to go to /textbooks and do search to see the results.

Comment: @SeongKim, you've defined the `search` method in `textbooks_controller` and also your routes defines to find the search method in textbooks controller. That's why it still goes to `/textbooks`. Define the method in `Home` controller   or manipulate the route.

Comment: I want to my Home page search goes to thre result of /textbooks

When I am at Home page and if I search book name "Algorithm"
I get URI => http://localhost:5000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Algoritm&commit=Search
Shows nothing.
But If I go to the /textbooks page and search "Algorithm" I can see the result.
The URI I see is : http://localhost:5000/textbooks?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Algorithm&commit=Search

Comment: @SeongKim, Check edited answer. Actually your search method is not doing the search right now.

Comment: I fixed like your advice to my TextbooksController.
But If you look my previous TextbooksController it has yours already in index method.

However I fixed the search method like yours. But still the home page search not working. it does not show any errors but I can see the results.

Comment: is there any `search.html.erb` file in your `views/textbooks` folder? If yes, then you can find the `@textbooks` variable there to iterate through the results.

Comment: Wow it is weird, If I erase <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search"> in my _navbar.html.erb, it is working.
I dont know why..

Comment: @SeongKim, then close the question. :)